# Painting a portion of a DataGridViewCells background with OnCellPainting, e.PaintBackground

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, paint, datagridcell

I'm overriding the OnCellPainting method so I can draw custom boarders for certain DataGridViewCells in a DataGridView

```
protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnCellPainting(e);
    PaintCellBorders(e);
}
```

Originally my borders were being painted then being painted over when the method `e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true)` is called.

I've since updated my code so that it paints the background first and then paints my boarders over the top. This approach works fine but ideally I'd like to be able to paint the background color inside the boarder I've drawn (using `e.Graphics.DrawLines(....)`)

To test the concept I've tried the following:

```
Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
e.PaintBackground(clipBounds, true);
e.Handled = true;
```

At the end of my method however it's painting the whole cell not just the portion I've specified by my rectangle, am I fundamentally missing anything?

Comment: Could be a typo, but the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs.paintbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) say that the `clipBounds` parameter is  _"a rectangle that specifies the area of the **DataGridView** to be painted."_, not the cell.

Comment: **facepalm** so I assume you can't paint a portion of a cell?

Comment: Have you studied the [CellPainting example in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_2)?  It is fairly comprehensive.